# Advice on designing django model with "exclusive" foreign key relationships

Tags: python, django-models

I want to design a Task model that can be associated to Project Models, another X model, and other Task models. The obvious choice is a foreign key, but I want any particular instance of that Task model to only be associated to only one of those model types, that is, if a Task model has a relationship with a Project model, it cannot have a relationship with another Task model, and so on. Any advice in what would be the best way to represent this? Thanks.

Comment: ForeignKey(unique=True) or OneToOneField()? Sorry if I've misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Yes, but unique = True would only limit the uniqueness to a particular foreign key, like tasks to Project, or tasks to X model, but would not be unique between all the foreign key models. One to on field would be the same thing, plus I need the ability for other models to have more than one Task object, but single Task objects should be related to only one other model.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Generic relation](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/). It lets you define a foreign key on multiple models. This way your task is only linked to one of your models.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is to inherit from a base class on all my models that will be related to tasks. Task models points to that base class on the ForeignKey with unique=True, and it seems like all subclasses inherit the relationship. Thanks.